# How to stop Outlook from editing html emails?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Well, I have created a html email signature that is displaying on almost al devices and email clients as intended. Its a little bit complex but its displaying correct.

Problem is Outlook (desktop application). It edits my message, before sending, wrapping everything in < p > tags and adding its own styles and bunch of other rules destroying the design.

I would switch to Thunderbird (no problems) but the firm is using MS Products and all the employees are familiar with Outlook and it would be a problem even suggesting another email client.

My question is:
**Is there a way to disable Outlook's meddling (inserting of its own styles and rules and paragraphs in particular) in my email and just send a clean unedited version without requiring users to take any extra steps?**

Comment: What is **Qutlook**?

Comment: @arkascha: Because they're considered beautiful.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Yep, indeed. Though only by those sending them ;-)

Comment: @arkascha
Well I do not know for what kind of company you are working for but a lot of firms use email for their campaigns hence the need for html email. Signatures are also being crafted in html emails because of enhanced formating options and because many more things.

If you don't see the power of it than you dont have to use it at all and why bother answering if you don't have anything to say that is of use.

Comment: You have a point there about security risks. But I react harshly to people who make comments/answera like yours that have nothing to do with a question and It's not relevant to it either. For your information a lot of people and companies use html emails and for example if ebay, or amozon is one of the so called companies with very little experience than you dont know what you are talking about. Please, if you don't know how to help dont be a smart ass with bunch of facts but no real solutions and let other people try.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with html email is that each browser does what it wants which makes creating a html email very annoying as you need to keep it as simple as possible to be multiclient. look at https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ to see which browser will take what.

Comment: Browsers are nowdays pretty much OK in comparison to 5 years ago but the email clients are still full of restrictions. I know very well what you mean and I managed to make my email look good across all clients that are of importance. What I want is to send my email through MS Outlook but prevent it from inserting its styles and rules much like the Mozilla Thunderbird does.

Comment: could you add your code or part of it so I could try and test?

Comment: Its a little bit big but this sample code will also do because I was testing with this too.

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JGrLYYmB

Comment: It is intended as signature with special offer and or campagin for certain gropu of customers. I put this in outlooks signatures folder and set it up as default signature for sending. When Outlook sends email with this sample code it wraps every thing in <p> tag except table tags and tags that come with it. Every image is put inside <p> tag and every text, span or div ... everything else.